# Slow down background animation CSS?

Tags: css, html

How do I slow down this animation and make it smoother for all browsers? Is there any possible way?

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
#animate-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-mark.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: animatedBackground 10s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, I do not need to know how to fix the image to center it or anything, I just would like to fix a similar image for the background on my own personal site.

Comment: can you be more precise? is it only about timing? if so, we have a plenty of duplicates

Comment: If you're experiencing lag I would recommend not animating background-position but use transform to translate the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply give the `animation` a longer duration.

The following changes it from `10s` to `30s`:

```css
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
#animate-area {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(https://github.githubassets.com/images/modules/open_graph/github-mark.png);
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation: animatedBackground 30s linear infinite alternate;
}
```

```html
<div id="animate-area"></div>
```